# How to combine and convert lists into one dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
Models = ["Model1","Model2","Model3","Model4","Model5","Model6"] Subsample = [0.9,1,0.8,0.6,0.6,0.5] 
Colsample = [0.7,1,1,0.8,0.7,0.7] 
Train-rmse = [0.342072,0.337006,0.33567,0.335309,0.356839,0.358312]
Valid-rmse = [0.384494,0.382689,0.385115,0.386509,0.389526,0.39074]
Modeling-rmse = [0.38449,0.38269,0.38511,0.38651,0.38953,0.39074]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([Models,Subsample,Colsamples,Train-rmse,Valid-rmse,Modeling-rmse]),columns = (["Models","Subsample","Colsample","Train-rmse","Valid-rmse","Modeling-rmse"])
```

Not able to combine and convert lists into a single dataframe, need suggestions!

Comment: Subsample and Colsamples lists are not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything is fine with your code, only you were using some illegal syntax for naming of variables. Don't use `-` in variable names.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

Models = ["Model1","Model2","Model3","Model4","Model5","Model6"]
Subsample = [0.9,1,0.8,0.6,0.6,0.5] 
Colsample = [0.7,1,1,0.8,0.7,0.7]
Train_rmse = [0.342072,0.337006,0.33567,0.335309,0.356839,0.358312]
Valid_rmse = [0.384494,0.382689,0.385115,0.386509,0.389526,0.39074]
Modeling_rmse = [0.38449,0.38269,0.38511,0.38651,0.38953,0.39074]

columns = ["Models","Subsample","Colsample","Train-rmse","Valid-rmse","Modeling-rmse"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([Models,Subsample,Colsample,Train_rmse,Valid_rmse,Modeling_rmse]), columns=columns)
```

Now it should work just fine.

Comment: Literally, not showing any output. It saying Jupyter-notebook is not trusted.

Comment: @sunnykevin It should not show any output, the data is saved to the dataframe. If you want to print it, do `print(df1)`.

Comment: I'm very sorry to ask naive question, I'm little bit out of my-mind. Thanks!

Comment: @sunnykevin No problem, it's a community for both newbies and seasoned developers. If I answered your question, consider accepting / upvoting -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers